# kdb how to have a conditional sum in select

Tags: kdb

How can I have a conditional sum in kdb, something like the following sql query

```
Select sum(qty > 0, qty, 0) as buy, sum(qty < 0, qty, 0) as sell from trades
```

I am looking for a way to do this without any where clause.

Comment: Can you share your expected output - not sure what the sql is supposed to be doing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using a lambda function inline on your select statement:

```
q)trades:([]sym:`a`b`c`d`e`f`g;qty:-34 -27 -11 50 19 -30 1)
q)select buy:sum {x where 0<x}[qty], sell:sum {x where 0>x}[qty] from trades
buy sell
--------
70  -102
```

Better method (with conditional):

```
q)select buy:sum ?[qty>0;qty;0], sell:sum ?[qty<0;qty;0] from trades
buy sell
--------
70  -102
```

Using 'min' and 'max' operators:

```
q)select buy:sum qty|0f,sell:sum qty&0f from trades
buy sell
--------
70  -102
```

Answer (score 5):

I would follow the first method proposed by @davidcrossey, but would simplify code a bit and remove anonymous functions:

```
select buy: sum qty where qty > 0, sell: sum qty where qty < 0 from trades
```

This query is preferable, because `?[;;]` works slower and consumes more space (~ 2 times). `min/max` approach is probably faster but consumes x2 space as well. You may use next code as performance test, `\ts` returns `time space` used by the query

```
trades: enlist[`qty]!enlist -50 + 1000000?100;
\ts select buy: sum qty where qty > 0, sell: sum qty where qty < 0 from trades
// returns 43 8389424
\ts select buy:sum ?[qty>0;qty;0], sell:sum ?[qty<0;qty;0] from     trades
// returns 68 17826560
\ts select buy:sum qty|0f,sell:sum qty&0f from trades
// returns 39 16777856
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case `<` & `>` are acting as vector conditional operators, hence passing the full columns works. **However, there are cases where a function needs the inputs as atoms, in that case, `each` can be used**.

```
q)trades:([]sym:`a`b`c`d`e`f`g;qty:-34 -27 -11 50 19 -30 1)
q)select buy:sum qty where {0<x}each qty, sell:sum qty where {0>x} each qty from trades
buy sell
--------
70  -102
```

You can now replace `{0<x}` to some more complex function that takes atoms as parameters and it should work fine.